# GCP Login policy for instances

Tags: ssh, password, google-cloud-platform, ssh-keys

Inside gcp instance, there is missing pam.d module. Also it has it's own wrapper over ssh, so you have to use glcoud tool's ssh to get into the instance. While it is easy to setup login lockout policy in AWS in the /etc/pam.d/password-auth, I have not found any documentation on how to do it in google. Should I just install the pam module and set the same settings as in AWS, and that way I can control after how many login attempts (key or password). All I want is to limit the amount of times users can try to login, regardless if it is password or key.

Comment: How about 'MaxAuthTries 1000' in sshd_config?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, must have been very late, I looked in the wrong directory. Nothing to do with google, it depends on what linux you are using in Google, or any cloud provider. I was using Centos, and the /etc/pam.d/password-auth and system-auth files were there. I was looking in the wrong folder.